# Share namespace/environment between instances of ipython

Tags: python, namespaces, ipython

I am searching for a hopefully not too hacky way of opening multiple instances of Ipython and sharing the namespace and environment. For example:

IPython in terminal 1:

```
x=1
```

IPython in terminal 2:

```
>x
1
```

Comment: You can't share namespaces across processes.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879465/ipython-storemagic-to-store-all-available-variables) question talks about a package called [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) which might be what your looking for.